# Optimizing an SQL query which uses multiple sub selects to display columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

So I have the following schema:

[image]

And I'm trying to obtain the data in the following format:

```
 ________________________________________
| Id | Property1 | Property2 | Property3 |
_________________________________________
| 123| Value1     | Value2     | Value3  |
 ________________________________________
```

So, the way I have composed the SQL query is like this:

```
SELECT
Id
,(SELECT pv.Value FROM CampaignProperty AS cp LEFT JOIN PropertyValue AS pv ON cp.Id = pv.CampaignPropertyId WHERE cp.Name = "Property1" AND pv.ContactId = c.Id AND cp.CampaignId = c.ActiveCampaignId) AS "Property1"
,(SELECT pv.Value FROM CampaignProperty AS cp LEFT JOIN PropertyValue AS pv ON cp.Id = pv.CampaignPropertyId WHERE cp.Name = "Property2" AND pv.ContactId = c.Id AND cp.CampaignId = c.ActiveCampaignId) AS "Property2"
,(SELECT pv.Value FROM CampaignProperty AS cp LEFT JOIN PropertyValue AS pv ON cp.Id = pv.CampaignPropertyId WHERE cp.Name = "Property3" AND pv.ContactId = c.Id AND cp.CampaignId = c.ActiveCampaignId) AS "Property3"
FROM Contact c
```

The problem I have is I've done that for over 10 properties, I have a couple of LEFT JOINs and multiple filters which make my query incredibly underperformant. After analysing this in SQL Management studio I figured that the bottleneck was in the SELECTs I showed above.

How could I obtain the same result but with better performance? Is there any other way to do the query?

It's important to note also that the `PropertyValue` table does not have indexes as of now...

Comment: There is no column called `CampaignProperty` in your data model.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `CampaignProperty` is a table, as well as `PropertyValue`. I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Nonetheless, I added the extra fields to the tables so it's more clear.

Comment: Please include alias with all column names

Comment: @paparazzo Done! :)

Comment: Key/value tables are always a nuisance to work with. Complicated and slow queries, the problem of telling optional from obligatory properties, different property types, property consistency ... It would be so easy had you simple columns instead. Are the properties so very different per contact/campaign that it is necessary to choose this abominable design?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner no, not really. In any case, this is for a migration to a new system, so that nuisance is soon over. The problem is the queries are sooooo slow it's actually the whole bottleneck of the migration solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little tricky because of the multiple levels of joining.  I think you want:

```
SELECT cp.ContactId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cp.Name = 'Property1' THEN pv.CampaignProperty END) as Property1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cp.Name = 'Property2' THEN pv.CampaignProperty END) as Property2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cp.Name = 'Property3' THEN pv.CampaignProperty END) as Property3
FROM Contact c LEFT JOIN
     CampaignProperty cp
     ON cp.ContactId = c.id AND
        cp.CampaignId = c.ActiveCampaignId LEFT JOIN
     PropertyValue pv
     ON cp.Id = pv.CampaignPropertyId
FROM Contact c
GROUP BY c.Id;
```

For performance, you want indexes on `CampaignProperty(ContactId, CampaignId, Id, Name)` and `PropertyValue(CampaignPropertyId, CampaignProperty)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do via single `SELECT` statement and do *aggregation* :

```
select c.id, max(case when cp.Name = 'Property1' then cp.value end) as Property1,
             max(case when cp.Name = 'Property2' then cp.value end) as Property2,
             max(case when cp.Name = 'Property3' then cp.value end) as Property3
from Contact c left join 
     CampaignProperty cp 
     on c.id = cp.ContactId left join
     PropertyValue pl 
     on pl.CampaignPropertyId = cp.id
group by c.id;
```

Comment: Your solution is the same as Gordon's. As I told him above, this takes 3 times as much as my initial query, benchmarked.

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano. . . Take a look at time and this would take advantage if you have proper indexed.

Comment: Yeah... the problem is we don't have indexes in the `PropertyValue` table. I think I should mention it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with multiple rows

```
SELECT c.ID, cp.Name, pv.Value 
  FROM Contact c     
  JOIN CampaignProperty AS cp 
    ON cp.CampaignId = c.ActiveCampaignId  
   AND cp.Name IN ('Property1', 'Property2', 'Property3')       
  LEFT JOIN PropertyValue AS pv 
    ON cp.Id = pv.CampaignPropertyId 
   AND pv.ContactId = c.Id 
 ORDER BY c.ID, cp1.Name
```